# Extension of proper map

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am dealing with some problems, which make me get stuck. It seems to me that I need to find an extension, given a proper map on a subset. Here are my questions:

1. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $A \subseteq M$ is a closed subset. Here is a proper map $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it right or not: $f$ can be extended continuously to proper map $F: M \rightarrow 
    \mathbb{R}$. I tried to puncture a euclidean space to construct a counterexample but failed.
2. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary, $U \subseteq M$ is an open neighborhood containing $\partial M$. Here is a smooth embedding $h: U\rightarrow \mathbb{H}^{2n+1}$. Can we extend it to a proper map $H: M\rightarrow \mathbb{H}^{2n+1}?$ If such a $H$ exists, can I request that there is a strict positive lower bound $\mu$ such that $H: IntM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}\times[\ \mu ,+\infty\ ]$?

In fact, question 2 appears when I try to deal with [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87940/whitney-embedding-for-manifolds-with-boundary). By collar neighborhood, the smooth embedding $h$ exists. If we find $H$ above, we can correct proper map to global smooth embedding step by step. Sincere appreciation for any help!

The definition of proper map here requests continuity. $\mathbb{H}^{2n+1}$ denotes closed 2n+1-dimensional upper half-space of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.

---

**Edit**: For question (2), let us assume that $h$ is some smooth embedding obtained from the collar neighborhood theorem. Can the required extension exist?

Comment: @User It can't be extended continuously. But is there a counterexample if we request closed subset. And collar neighborhood also gives a smooth embedding on a closed neighborhood. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the assumption "closed." Anyway, any continuous map defined on a closed subset of a manifold can be extended continuously to the whole manifold as any manifold is a normal space, see [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem)

Comment: @User I want the extension to be proper. I missed that. I will edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $A \subseteq M$ is a closed subset. Here is a proper map $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it right or not: $f$ can be extended continuously to $F: M \rightarrow 
>     \mathbb{R}$.

By Tietze extension theorem every such map has a continuous extension. But I assume you want the extension to be proper as well. Such extension does not have to exist. Here's an example: consider $M=\mathbb{R}$, $A_n=[2\cdot n, 2\cdot n+1]$ and $A=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n$. Clearly $A$ is closed. Now define

$$f:A\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x &\text{if }x\in A_n\text{ and }n\text{ is odd}\\
-x &\text{if }x\in A_n\text{ and }n\text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}$$

The map is continuous and proper (because $f^{-1}(X)\subseteq X\cup -X$). I will show that no continuous extension of $f$ is proper.

Assume that $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is its continuous extension. Then by the intermediate value theorem $F(x)=0$ for infinitely many $x$, at least one in between every two consecutive $[2\cdot n, 2\cdot n+1]$ intervals. More precisely for any $n$ there is $x\in [2\cdot n+1, 2\cdot n+2]$ such that $F(x)=0$. Hence the preimage $F^{-1}(0)$ is not bounded and thus not compact.

> 2. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary, $U \subseteq M$ is an open neighborhood containing $\partial M$. Here is a smooth embedding $h: U\rightarrow \mathbb{H}^{2n+1}$. Can we extend it to a proper map $H: M\rightarrow \mathbb{H}^{2n+1}?$

Not necessarily. Consider $M=\mathbb{H}^1=[0,\infty)$. Then $\partial M=\{0\}$. Now consider $U=[0,1)$ and let $h:U\to\mathbb{H}^1$ be given by $h(x)=tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$. This is a smooth embedding, in fact a diffeomorphism (actually any diffeomorphism will work). But $\lim_{x\to 1}h(x)=\infty$ and so $h$ cannot be extended to $1$ in a continuous way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! For(1), it is just what I want. For(2), I think it's my fault for not offering sufficient conditions. Your answer is absolutely right. But my purpose is to extend a smooth embedding obtained from the collar neighborhood. The neighborhood can be either open or closed. So can we extend some smooth embedding obtained from the collar neighborhood to satisfy the request in (2)? For example, $h: F\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n} \times [0,\frac{1}{2}]$, $F$ a closed subset. Anyway, Thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: @MarkJoe if you assume that the collar neighbourhood is closed instead of open, then we are back at point (1), no? If I remove an open interval inside each $A_n$ then this new $M$ has boundary intersecting each $A_n$, and thus $A$ becomes a collar neighourhood of it. I don't need to change the function's definition (except removing points it is not well defined at), the rest of the argument stands.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right. So it doesn't seem to get through by extending a local smooth embedding to a global one for manifold with boundary. It disappoints me, but I learn a lot from your answer. Sincere thanks.